# Short story, possibly Asimov, about an engineer sabotaging a floating city's engines, causing it to crash on Earth and killing everyone on board

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, isaac-asimov

This short story is about an engineer who sabotages the engines on a floating city where the rich and well-to-do live apart from normal humanity causing it to crash on Earth killing everyone on board...

Answer (score 41):

That would be [Shah Guido G.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shah_Guido_G.) (1951), I believe.

It is, indeed by Asimov, and is one of the stories where the entire plot is nothing but the setup for an atrocious pun. (Specifically, it's what's referred to as a '[Shaggy Dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaggy_dog_story)' story.  Don't believe me?  Look at the title again.. Shah - Gui - doG.)

Short synopsis:  The floating city has been hovering on the edge of it's maximum load limit for a while.  The 'hero' of the story arranges for all of the Guardians (the 'Waves'), in their ships, to land at once, overloading the generators that kept the city afloat, and causing it to come crashing to the ground.

This is all for the pun that, once again, Atlantis (for so the floating city was named)

> sank beneath the waves.

Comment: Your answer is good but my memory of that story is not.

Comment: Sweet angry cats! That's *horrible*! I am glad this story (apparently) sank out of sight... Asimov, were he alive, were ought to have been ashamed. Huff huff! Etc.

Comment: This description reminds me of another short story, by Arthur C. Clarke: the '*Star Mangled Spanner*' - wordplay turned into a rather far-fetched tale :)

Comment: Huh. For some reason, I was thinking that was the story that ended with the line parodying "Give My Regards to Broadway", but that's apparently "Death of a Foy".

Comment: I much prefer Spider Robinson or Robert Asprin for punny stories :p

Comment: At 32 seconds this is officially the fastest-ever answer on SFF.SE (with the exception of self-answers). Congrats!

Comment: This is definitely Shah Guido G. Why has,'t it be accepted yet ?

Comment: @Alfred -- Check the OP's profile -- "Last seen Dec 7 '14 at 22:26"  Since that is the same time the question was asked, OP probably hasn't been back, or, at least, not on that account.